# Node in multiple linked list

Tags: database-design, graph, neo4j

In our NEO4j Graph we created serval linked list of top items for a specified category.

Example:

Top-50 Week 2016-01
- Mike Posner
- Afrojack
- Willy William

At this point we created this:

```
 (node top 50 week 201601)-[first]->(node mike posner)-[next]->(node afrojack)-[next]->(node willy).
```

But now the next week, the order is changed to Willy, Mike, Afro. And now we end up with having multiple next relationships on each artist. Traversal the list will be significantly slower.

Any idea, how we could model this in a better way.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @stdob-- is more than valid, however this doesn't scale well.

Imagine you want to find all artists that ever been number 1 and how many times, you'll have to match ALL of them as well as traversing ALL relationships and filter on the rank property. Which will be a nightmare if you have 1 million artists.

The idea of LinkedList is fine, but the nodes in the LinkedList can be for example a `RankItem` node which will be related to the artist.

```
(week1)-[:FIRST]->(rankItem)<-[:HAS_RANKING_POSITON]-(artist)
```

for the previous question, you can simply do :

```
MATCH (w:Week)-[:FIRST]->()<-[:HAS_RANKING_POSITION]-(artist)
RETURN artist, count(*) as occurences
```

Depending on the queries you'll need to do, sometimes it makes sense also to have a RankingList that the RankItem will connect to also.

```
(ranking {v:1})-[:NEXT]->(ranking {v:2})-[:NEXT]->(.....
```

in that case, the RankingItem will connect also to the list

making things more performant for questions like :

> Based on an Artist, find me artists that have a common pattern of
>   ranking history

Comment: What if we need to count how many times the artist is in the top-10 or top-25?

Comment: easy, `MATCH (w:Week)-[:FIRST|:NEXT*10]->(rank)<-[:HAS_RANING_POSITION]-(artist) RETURN artist, count(*)`

Comment: Exactly. Your version of the linked list is better than my decision. In particular it allows to store additional information in the intermediate node `rankItem`.

Comment: Yes definitely, you can also combine the RankItem linked lists with a timetree (works pretty well)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will approach this model:

```
(T1:Top {name:'Top week1'})-[:include {rank:0}]->(P1:Person {name: 'mike posner'})
(T1:Top {name:'Top week1'})-[:include {rank:1}]->(P1:Person {name: 'afrojack'})
(T1:Top {name:'Top week1'})-[:include {rank:2}]->(P1:Person {name: 'willy'})

(T2:Top {name:'Top week2'})-[:include {rank:1}]->(P1:Person {name: 'mike posner'})
(T2:Top {name:'Top week2'})-[:include {rank:0}]->(P1:Person {name: 'afrojack'})
(T2:Top {name:'Top week2'})-[:include {rank:2}]->(P1:Person {name: 'willy'})

(T3:Top {name:'Top week3'})-[:include {rank:2}]->(P1:Person {name: 'mike posner'})
(T3:Top {name:'Top week3'})-[:include {rank:1}]->(P1:Person {name: 'afrojack'})
(T3:Top {name:'Top week3'})-[:include {rank:0}]->(P1:Person {name: 'willy'})
```

[image]

And query to get top of the specific week:

```
MATCH (T:Top {name:'TOP week1'})-[r:include]->(P:Person) 
RETURN P.name, r.rank ORDER BY r.rank
```